# problemas con c++ El identificador no esta especificado

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dev-c++, visual-c++

hola recientemente estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal en c++, originalmente el código se escribo en C.

tengo esta linea de código:

```
system("COLOR 0A");
```

Donde me da el siguiente error: "El identificador "system" no esta definido.

Así mismo me pasa en dos lineas más donde pongo getch(); "el identificador getch no esta definido"

las librerías que estoy ocupando son:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstring>
```

Asi mismo estoy trabajando con una raíz cuadrado la linea de código es:

```
radio = sqrt((pow(valorH, 2)) + (pow(valorK, 2)) - valorF);
```

Donde las variables están definidas como doubles. y me da el siguiente error: "Mas de una instancia de función sobrecargada "sqrt" coincide con la lista de argumentos.

He logrado solucionar la mayoría de errores que me dio al pasar el código a c++ sin embargo estos errores no logro solucionarlos alguien sabrá alguna manera de solucionar o a que se deben. les agradecería mucho si pueden apoyarme, estoy haciendo la app en visual-studio

Comment: En C++ las funciones de la librería estándar están en el namespace `std`. Si no escribiste `using namespace std;` deberías escribirlas así: `std::cout`, `std::system`, etc. Pruebalo por si a caso.

Comment: probe esa solucion ya que si escribi el using namespace, pero al ponerlo de la forma std::system me sale el error: "Espacio de nombre std no tiene ningun miebro llamado "system" " :(

Comment: he probado a compilar desde visual code por medio de terminal y me ha abierto sin problemas, sera algun problema con el compilador de visual estudii ??

Comment: Depende de qué compilador estés usando. Si usas el de Visual Studio no deberías tener ningún problema. Pero si usas alguno externo puede que no hayas configurado bien el proyecto.

Comment: si estoy usando el de visual studio por eso se me hace raro ya que el proyecto corria en una pc antigua que tenia desde visual, sin embargo ahora no me esta funcionando en visual studio, pero si en code, y codeblocks :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error puede ser reproducir con [este sencillo código](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//@/LD8zRSGtNC85Mz9PIy0nP7FEU6G6lgtFOCW/NCknFSzOlZlXopCbmJmnoclVzcUJU2Goac3FWZRaUlqUp2BgzVX7/z8A):

```
void funcion(float) {}
void funcion(double) {}

int main()
{
    funcion(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Si te fijas, a `funcion` le hemos pasado un `1` que es un entero (`int`). Los enteros pueden convertirse implícitamente a número en coma flotante (`float`) o número en coma flotante de doble precisión (`double`) pero el compilador no sabe cuál de las dos conversiones quieres que se lleve a cabo porque ambas conversiones implícitas son igual de válidas.

La solución es decírselo:

> ```
> radio = sqrt(static_cast<float>((pow(valorH, 2)) + (pow(valorK, 2)) - valorF));
> ```

o

> ```
> radio = sqrt(static_cast<double>((pow(valorH, 2)) + (pow(valorK, 2)) - valorF));
> ```

Comment: gracias, si me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Esto no debería ir como respuesta, pero tampoco podría escribirlo en un comentario.

El caso es que te dejo un fragmento de código que replica tu duda, a ver si por ahí puedes ver dónde está el problema:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double radio = 0;
    double valorH = 3;
    double valorK = 2;
    double valorF = 1;
    radio = sqrt((pow(valorH, 2)) + (pow(valorK, 2)) - valorF);
    cout<<radio<<endl;
    //system ("clear");
    return 0;
}
```

He comentado el `system` para que no se ejecute. Esta opción limpia la pantalla en linux. Si estás en Windows sería "cls". Si te da error eso de "COLOR 0A" puede ser porque en la consola de Windows no existe ese comando, aunque no estoy seguro.

Comment: el comando "COLOR 0A" lo uso para indicar el color de fondo y texto de la consola, lo curiso es que tengo ese comando en mas partes pero con diferentes argumentos por ejemplo COLOR 4E y me funciona al igual que el getch solo son 3 lineas de codigo donde me dice que no esta especificado el indentificador, y lo de la razi cuadrada desconozco el porque me esta mandado el error que menciono arriba

Comment: Es raro lo de la sobrecarga. ¿Mira a ver si en la documentación de Microsoft te puede aclarar algo. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-change-history-2003-2015?view=msvc-170

Comment: Otra cosa....¿puedes poner un ejemplo completo del código que da error?

Answer (score 0):

el codigo completo donde involucro a la raiz cuadrada es:

claro mira el codigo completo que involucra la raiz cuadrada es:

```
cout << "\n\nCapture el valor de H\n";
            cout << "[   ]\b\b\b\b";
            cin >> valorH;

            cout << "\n\nCapture el valor de K\n";
            cout << "[   ]\b\b\b\b";
            cin >> valorK;

            cout << "\n\nCapture el valor de F\n";
            cout << "[   ]\b\b\b\b";
            cin >> valorF;

            radio = sqrt((pow(valorH, 2)) + (pow(valorK, 2)) - valorF);

            cout << "\n\nEl valor del RADIO es igual a:\n\n" << radio << endl;
            cout << "\n\n";
            cout << "Presione una tecla para continuar" << endl;
            getch();
            system("cls");
```

mientras que en el caso de System y getch los uso solo cuando limpio pantalla con System("cls") y getch para que espere respuesta para seguir avanzando. revisare la info que compartiste para ver si puedo resolver algo.

Comment: El exponente debería ser `double`. Prueba a poner 2.0 en lugar de 2 
  https://m.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Comment: He probado la solucion sin obtener un resoltado positivo ://